# Is there a way to send data to server using 'unload\navigator.sendBeacon' + 'GraphQL'?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js

On tab\browser close I need to send data to server. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47108290/4992248) (based on [this blog](http://usefulangle.com/post/62/javascript-send-data-to-server-on-page-exit-reload-redirect)) which recommends to use `sendBeacon`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516743/how-can-i-send-a-graphql-ajax-query-with-a-variable) is shown how the data must be prepared in order to send them to server via Ajax. I repeated the structure from the answer:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', this.sendDataToServer, false)

sendDataToServer () {
    myData = JSON.stringify({
    'mutation': `mutation EmailAuth($email: String!, $password: String!) {
        getOrCreateUser(email: $email, password: $password) {
        token
        }
    }
    `,
    'variables': {email: 'test@test.net', password: 'Test'}
    })

    navigator.sendBeacon('http://localhost:8000/graphql', myData)
}
```

In this case Django shows: `"POST /graphql HTTP/1.1" 400 53`

I also found in internet the version with `Blob`:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', this.sendDataToServer, false)

sendDataToServer () {
    let headers = {
        type: 'application/json'
    }
    let myBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify({
        'mutation': `mutation EmailAuth($email: String!, $password: String!) {
            getOrCreateUser(email: $email, password: $password) {
            token
            }
        }
        `,
        'variables': {email: 'test@test.net', password: 'Test'}
    })], headers)

    navigator.sendBeacon('http://localhost:8000/graphql', myBlob)
}
```

but in this case there is no any Django's reaction at all.

How can I wrap my data on a frontend side into GraphQL format and put it in `sendBeacon` in the way, which can be accepted by server side?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon Yeah, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @KevinB, the question is clarified

Comment: yeah i don't understand the mutate/whatever part of this, if it results in an ajax request being sent, it can be done with sendBeacon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found why `Blob` does not work, with a help of using button instead of `unload`. The issue is with chrome browser. Console shows: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'sendBeacon' on 'Navigator': sendBeacon() with a Blob whose type is not any of the CORS-safelisted values for the Content-Type request header is disabled temporarily. See http://crbug.com/490015 for details.`

Django is waiting for request of `application/json` type, which according to the [link from error](http://crbug.com/490015) is not safe.

For Firefox this issue can be fixed using Django's package `corsheaders` and add `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True` to the settings.